# nokogiri encoder error with cyrillic letters - is that a bug?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

The following code produces:

encoding error : output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0xE8 0xED 0xF4 0xEE
   I/O error : encoder error

When cyrillic letters are included in XML, text assigned executionContext everything works fine. Assignend to .content is intentional. I need to convert XML brackets to < stuff.

```
#!/bin/env ruby
# encoding: Windows-1251

.....

    executionContext =  
        '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1251"?>
        <vco:execution-context xmlns:vco="http://www.vmware.com/vco" xmlns="vco">
            <vco:parameters>
                <vco:parameter name="информация" type="string" description="" scope="local">        
                    <vco:string>&lt;operation&gt;информация&lt;/operation&gt;</vco:string>
                </vco:parameter>
            </vco:parameters>
        </vco:execution-context>'




    docExCon = Nokogiri.XML(executionContext)

    docExCon.at( '//vco:string' ).content = '<operation>информация</operation>'
```

Comment: What source encoding are you using?

Comment: As you see windows-1251 in XML, ruby script starts with #!/bin/env ruby
# encoding: Windows-1251

Comment: If the encoding is consistent you shouldn't get errors like this, though I've only used UTF-8 for these things.

Comment: "you shouldn't get errors like this" I believe nokogiri don't know about it ;-)

Comment: Well I replaced windows-1251 with UTF-8 - it works

Comment: That leads me to wonder if your source is actually UTF-8 encoded despite what you've said in the header.